# How to access a phpmyadmin db from a website

Tags: html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am an absolutely new to html and coding, and don't understand how to link a website to a phpmyadmin database. I already have a working domain, and I want to be able to access my phpmyadmin database (localhost) in order display some tables and information into my website from an sql query. Is there any specific code I need to enter to access the db or do I need to make a web application?

Comment: **phpMyAdmin** is s tool written in PHP for maintaining and manipulating a **MYSQL** database. **phpMyAdmin** is not a database!

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or code conversion or tutorial or library finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can get access to phpMyAdmin trough your websites control panel.

Mostly something like this: http://example.com:8880 Or something similar.

Sometimes its also possible to go into phpMyAdmin by adding /phpmyadmin after the url. So that would make it http://example.com/phpmyadmin

I recommend you to go to this website: http://www.w3schools.com/ to learn about programming and databases.

For database connections trough PHP
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

Comment: Just read my whole awnser. w3schools explains exacly what you want. You wanna fetch data from the database. If you new to this, just learn from there and try it yourself.

Comment: Its also pretty uncommon for people to recommend going to `w3fools` on SO without getting some kind of downvote. It is not considered a very reliable resource by most people who lurk here

Comment: Nvm you are not the guy that asked the question :o. But w3schools is a good website for people who wanna learn the basics. And of course there are plenty of other websites. I just give him a tip.

Comment: In the help: ___Off Topic___ Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Yes, i think you are right. You are longer a member of SO than iam. I just though it was a good start for him. Well, i can delete my awnser if they want.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that I want to be able to access the database through HTML forms. Is this possible? I know what phpmyadmin does and I have been able to access the database through a mysql client.